# Working on the same app in Xcode without a team account

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an iOS project and configured the app in iTunes Connect. A friend wants to join the development. We use Git and have individual Apple accounts (no company account). How can I enable other developers to work on the same project without an Apple team account? They should have access to the same leaderboards in Game Center etc. Is this possible? I have no idea, which files/certificates need to be exported for the other developers.

Comment: You could just export your development/distribution certificates and private key, and they could build it as if they were you.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. I used the "export accounts" function in XCode.

Comment: I'll repost it as an answer and perhaps you could accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(repost of comment, with elaboration)

**Method 1:**

You could just export your development/distribution certificates and private key, and they could build it as if they were you.

To do this, open the **Keychain Access** app on your Mac, and look for **My Certificates** in the left-hand menu. In there, you should see your development and/or distribution certificates *and* private key. Right-click on a certificate and one of the options will let you export it.

If you can't see anything in **My Certificates**, check the various keychains. Your default keychain should be called **login** but some users may store them elsewhere.

**Method 2:**

Open Xcode and navigate to **Xcode --> Preferences** and click on the **Accounts** tab along the top of the window that opens. In here, select your Apple ID that your developer account belong to, and then select your individual or company name and press the **View Details** button.

In the top half of the window that opens, select your signing identity and then on the cog symbol (next to the **+** button) and you can press **Export**.

Comment: Looks like sometimes it's not enough. Here in Xcode 10.2, when I'm trying to export to AppStore, Xcode says it can't find correct certificates, but I can see them in Keychain with correct private key.